# Bookdown caption in knitr include_graphics

Tags: knitr, caption, bookdown

I am writing a report with Bookdown and I am interested in reproducing a series of pictures horizontally with one single caption which describes them all. If I dont define the `fig.cap` I get the pictures correct as follows:

````
```{r, out.width = "33%",echo=FALSE}

knitr::include_graphics(rep(c("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"),1))

```
````

[image]

If instead I want to add a caption that describes all of the three pictures as follows I get the result below:

````
(ref:123) left: ...; centre ...; right ....

```{r, out.width = "33%",fig.cap='(ref:123)', echo=FALSE}

knitr::include_graphics(rep(c("one.jpg","two.jpg","three.jpg"),1))

```
````

[image]

What I would like instead is something like this:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the chunk option `fig.show='hold'`. See [Figures 2.3 and 2.4](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html) in the **bookdown** book for examples.